# Why won't my image transfer from my files into my stylesheet for a DIV?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replicate a webpage template solely for the purpose of becoming more familiar with the works of HTML/CSS. I want to use an image in my documents as a background for a DIV, but for some odd reason, it will not import. Keep in mind, I'm still pretty new to coding.

I pulled a random stock photo address off of Google as a test, and that would work. So, I'm thinking either I have the photo located in the wrong folder (It's in the same exact folder as the document I'm calling it from), or there's something else in my code that is conflicting with the called image/file. I'm still not sure, though.

HTML file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>conquer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="conquer.css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="navbar">
        <a href="">Homepage</a>
        <a href="">About Us</a>
        <a href="">Services</a> 
        <a href="">Contact</a>
        <a href="">External</a>
    </div>

    <div class="topbanner"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS file:

```
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
}

/** Navigation Bar **/

.navbar {
    background-color: #383E4C;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.navbar a {
    color: #F6F6F7;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #646D7C;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #49505F;
}

/** Top Banner **/

.topbanner {
    height: 500px;
    width: 300px;
    background-image: url('/city.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I want the image to display in the DIV, but when I open the console elements, it's just a huge invisible block.

Comment: Open your page in a browser and press `F12` to access the developer console. Do you see any errors that say `404 Not Found`, specifically mentioning `/city.jpg`?

Comment: Have you tried `./city.jpg` or just `city.jpg` , not sure what your directory structure is...

Comment: If all of your files are in the same folder, use `url('city.jpg');`

Answer (score 3):

In paths, the leading slash /, tells the browser to goto the ROOT folder.

So you will want to change this:

```
background-image: url('/city.jpg');
```

to

```
background-image: url('city.jpg');
```